# Bootstrap nav-pills doesn't work

Tags: bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm new in Bootstrap, and I'm building a simple application for showing list of products. But I noticed that `nav-pills` has no CSS effect on the navigation below the table of products.

This is the detailed HTML I'm using as a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Produits</title>
</head>
<body>
</br>
</br>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Liste des Produits</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Désignation</th>
                <th>Prix</th>
                <th>Quantité</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="p:${listProduits}">
                <td th:text="${p.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${p.designation}"></td>
                <td th:text="${p.prix}"></td>
                <td th:text="${p.quantite}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
<div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li role="presentation" th:each="page,status:${totalPages}">
                <a href="#" th:text="${status.index}"> </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I'm using Thymeleaf for template engine.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What effect do you expect? Their `href` contains only a `#`.

Comment: I' m talking about boostrap decorating effect  not click event effect on each item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set the required classes on the `ul` element, but according to the [Nav Pills documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#pills), you need to add `nav-item` class to the `li` elements, and `nav-link` class to the `a` elements:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```